# Price filtering in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on e-commerce React/Redux project, I want to make functionality by which user can display the products according to price slider, I have made two input fields in which user can type min and max price value,This functionality is working on button click, but I want on change event, As the user type second value it filters product **onChange**,

can anyone help me to sort this issue, Thanks in advance, My code and screenshot is attached below

---

```
class PriceInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: props.values,
        };
        this.onValueChangeComplete = this.onValueChangeComplete.bind(this);
    }

    onValueChangeComplete() {
        const { onValueChange } = this.props;

        onValueChange(this.state.value);
    }


    render() {
        const { currencyCode, limits } = this.props;
        const { value } = this.state;
        const notChanged = _.isEqual(value, limits);

        return (
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
              <div className={styles.inputWrapper}>
                  {I18n.getComponent(
                      (formattedValue) =>
                          <input
                              type="text"
                              name="min"
                              className={styles.textInput}
                              placeholder={formattedValue}
                          />,
                      'filter.price-range-min'
                  )}
                <span className={styles.between}>{I18n.getText('filter.price-aed', {}, 'To')}</span>
                  {I18n.getComponent(
                      (formattedValue) =>
                          <input
                              type="text"
                              name="max"
                              className={styles.textInput}
                              placeholder={formattedValue}
                          />,
                      'filter.price-range-min'
                  )}
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Component in which I have to used the price functionality

```
case 'price':
                            childComponent = (
                                <PriceInput values={facet.data}
                                    limits={facet.data}
                                    currencyCode={this.props.currency.code}
                                    onValueChange={(data) => this.onSearchChange(facet.code, data)}/>
                            );
                            break;
```

[image]

Comment: In the second `input` element, set `onChange` and check whether both inputs already have value set. If true, manually trigger the button click event.

Comment: can you plz tell, how to use onChange event @Hemerson

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna be something like:

```
handleMaxChange(event) {
  const minValue = '' // I'm assuming you already have max's value saved somewhere
  const { value } = event.target

  if (minValue && value) {
    this.props.onValueChange(/* send values here */)
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <input
      type="text"
      name="max"
      className={styles.textInput}
      placeholder={formattedValue}
      onChange=={handleMaxChange}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: minValue is to be set by user, there are two input box, one for min price and one for max price, product will display whic lie in min and max value

Comment: Simply do the same for both inputs.